# Problemas con propiedad border-radius en tabla

Tags: html, css3

Hola tengo una tabla y no hay manera que me muestre en los navegadores(chrome y firefox) la propiedad border radius. Solo en internet explorer logre que se vea el efecto. Alguien que me pueda ayudar con esto ?

Gracias

```css
.tabla_recibido td:first-child {
  width: 150px;
  padding-right: 30px;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

.tabla_recibido td:nth-child(2) {
  width: 130px;
  padding-right: 30px
}

.tabla_recibido tr:nth-child(2) {
  border-bottom: 0.5px solid
}

.tabla_recibido tr:nth-child(3) {
  border-bottom: 0.5px solid
}

.tabla_recibido tr:nth-child(4) {
  border-bottom: 0.5px solid
}

.tabla_recibido td:last-child {
  width: 250px;
  /*border-bottom-right-radius: 6px;
        border-left: 0.5px solid*/
}


/*.tabla_recibido tr:first-child td:first-child{border-top-left-radius: 20px}
    .tabla_recibido tr:first-child td:last-child{border-top-right-radius: 20px}
    .tabla_recibido tr:first-child td:only-child{border-top-right-radius: 20px; 
    border-top-left-radius: 20px}*/

.tabla_recibido h6 {
  font-size: 0.8em
}

.tabla_recibido td {
  padding: 2px;
  text-align: justify;
  /*border: 0.5px solid;*/
}

.tabla_recibido li {
  list-style: none;
}

.tabla_recibido {
  border: 1px solid;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
```

```html
<table class="tabla_recibido">
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="fila1">
    <td id="logo_recibido">
      <img src="../../../img/logo.png">
    </td>
    <td colspan="2">
      <h5><b>XXXXXXXX</b></h5>
      <h5>Nombre del trabajador</h5>
      <h5>Ruc: 17xxxxx</h5>
      <h5>Direccion: Avexxxxxxxxx</h5>
      <h5>Telefono: 097xxxxxxx</h5>
    </td>
    <td>
      <h3><b>Orden:</b></h3>
      <h1 id="orden"># 0000{!! $equipo->id !!}</h1>
      <ul>

        <li><b>Fecha de ingreso: </b>{!! date('d-m-Y',strtotime($equipo->created_at)) !!}</li>
        <li>Valor: $ ___________</li>
        <li>Abono: $ ___________</li>
        <li>Saldo: $ ___________</li>
      </ul>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="cuerpo_recibido">
    <td colspan="2">
      <h4>Datos del Cliente:</h4>
      <h5>Nombre: <small>{!! $equipo->cliente->nombres !!}</small></h5>
      <h5>Apellidos: <small>{!! $equipo->cliente->apellidos !!}</small></h5>
      <h5>Cédula: <small>{!! $equipo->cliente->cedula !!}</small></h5>
      <h5>Teléfono: <small>{!! $equipo->cliente->telefono !!}</small></h5>
      <h5>Dirección: <small>{!! $equipo->cliente->direccion !!}</small></h5>
    </td>
    <td colspan="2">
      <h4>Datos del Equipo:</h4>
      <h5>Identificador: <small>{!! $equipo->identificador !!}</small></h5>
      <h5>Marca: <small>{!! $equipo->marca->name !!}</small></h5>
      <h5>Modelo: <small>{!! $equipo->modelo !!}</small></h5>
      <h5>Color: <small>{!! $equipo->color !!}</small></h5>
      <h5>Daño: <small>{!! $equipo->descripcion !!}</small></h5>
      <h6>Los Equipos xxxxx abandonados por lo tanto <b><i>Ingxxx</i></b>, no se responsabiliza del la devolución del mismo.</h6>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2">
      <h6><b>NOTA:</b> El cliente declara ser el propietario legitimo del equipo, y que fue adquirido
        <b><i>Lítitamente</i></b>, por lo cual autoriza la reparacion en nuestro taller.</h6>
    </td>
    <td>
      <h4>Accesorios:</h4>
    </td>

    <td>


      <ul>
        <li>Chip_____</li>
        <li>Bateria_____</li>
        <li>Cargador_____</li>
      </ul>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2">
      <h5>Firma cliente</h5>
    </td>
    <td colspan="2">
      <h5>Firma conforme</h5>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: puedes colocar el código para verificar donde esta el error.

Comment: Te recomiendo leer: [¿Cómo elaboro una buena pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Leer [Cómo crear un ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable.](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Reformula la pregunta y coloca el codigo para poder ayudarte.

Answer (score 1):

No he entendido que quieres hacer, pero creo entender que es lo que te sucede, para explicarte te pongo un ejemplo con 5 tipo de tablas:

```css
body{ font-family: sans-serif; }

h4{text-transform: uppercase; }

table{
  background: red;
  border: solid 1px gray;
  border-radius: 20px;
  font-size: 12px;
}

td{  
  background: white;
  padding: 0.5em;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 1em lightgray;
}

.tipo2, .tipo3, .tipo4{
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

/*De esta forma haras aparecer un borde*/  
.tipo3{
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 1px cyan;
}

.tipo3, .tipo4{
  overflow: hidden;
}

.tipo4 td{
  border-radius: 2em;
}

.tipo5 tr:first-child td:first-child{
  border-radius: 20px 0 0 0;
}

.tipo5 tr:first-child td:last-child{
  border-radius: 0 20px 0 0;
}

.tipo5 tr:last-child td:first-child{
  border-radius: 0 0 0 20px;
}

.tipo5 tr:last-child td:last-child{
  border-radius: 0 0 20px 0;
}
```

```html
<h4>tabla tipo1</h4>
<table class="tipo1">
  <tr>
    <td>contenido celda</td>
    <td>contenido celda</td>
    <td>contenido celda</td>
    <td>contenido celda</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>contenido celda</td>
    <td>contenido celda</td>
    <td>contenido celda</td>
    <td>contenido celda</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>contenido celda</td>
    <td>contenido celda</td>
    <td>contenido celda</td>
    <td>contenido celda</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>contenido celda</td>
    <td>contenido celda</td>
    <td>contenido celda</td>
    <td>contenido celda</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<h4>tabla tipo2</h4>
<table class="tipo2">
  <tr>
    <td>contenido celda</td>
    <td>contenido celda</td>
    <td>contenido celda</td>
    <td>contenido celda</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>contenido celda</td>
    <td>contenido celda</td>
    <td>contenido celda</td>
    <td>contenido celda</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>contenido celda</td>
    <td>contenido celda</td>
    <td>contenido celda</td>
    <td>contenido celda</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>contenido celda</td>
    <td>contenido celda</td>
    <td>contenido celda</td>
    <td>contenido celda</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<h4>tabla tipo3</h4>
<table class="tipo3">
  <tr>
    <td>contenido celda</td>
    <td>contenido celda</td>
    <td>contenido celda</td>
    <td>contenido celda</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>contenido celda</td>
    <td>contenido celda</td>
    <td>contenido celda</td>
    <td>contenido celda</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>contenido celda</td>
    <td>contenido celda</td>
    <td>contenido celda</td>
    <td>contenido celda</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>contenido celda</td>
    <td>contenido celda</td>
    <td>contenido celda</td>
    <td>contenido celda</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<h4>tabla tipo4</h4>
<table class="tipo4">
  <tr>
    <td>contenido celda</td>
    <td>contenido celda</td>
    <td>contenido celda</td>
    <td>contenido celda</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>contenido celda</td>
    <td>contenido celda</td>
    <td>contenido celda</td>
    <td>contenido celda</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>contenido celda</td>
    <td>contenido celda</td>
    <td>contenido celda</td>
    <td>contenido celda</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>contenido celda</td>
    <td>contenido celda</td>
    <td>contenido celda</td>
    <td>contenido celda</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<h4>tabla tipo5</h4>
<table class="tipo5">
  <tr>
    <td>contenido celda</td>
    <td>contenido celda</td>
    <td>contenido celda</td>
    <td>contenido celda</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>contenido celda</td>
    <td>contenido celda</td>
    <td>contenido celda</td>
    <td>contenido celda</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>contenido celda</td>
    <td>contenido celda</td>
    <td>contenido celda</td>
    <td>contenido celda</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>contenido celda</td>
    <td>contenido celda</td>
    <td>contenido celda</td>
    <td>contenido celda</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

A la todas las tablas les he puesto:

- Un fondo rojo
- Un borde gris
- Las celdas de color blanco
- Una sombra interna gris
- Un borde redondeado de 20px

Y a las celdas:

- Un fondo blanco
- Un espaciado interno de 0.5em para separar las letras de los bordes
- Y un efecto de sombra interna, para que se noten los límites de las celdas

La primera tabla, **tipo 1**, no tiene una propiedad llamada `border-collapse`qué es la causante de la separación o no, entre las celdas de la tabla, como no se la aplique, **se puede ver el fondo rojo de la tabla entre las celdas, como si tuvieran un borde**. Sin esta propiedad se puede ver perfectamente el borde redondeado.

La tabla **tipo 2** tiene aplicado la propiedad `border-collapse´, que como ves **hace que no se vea el borde redondeado de la tabla** porque te comentaron arriba, el fondo de cada celda las oculta. Esta misma propiedad se la aplique a la tabla **tipo 3** y **tipo 4**.

La tabla **tipo 3**, si queremos ver los bordes redondeados, pues sencillamente aplicamos un `overflow: hidden` a toda la tabla, **para que lo que sobresalga de esta** (en este caso los fondos de las celdas cuadradas), **se "oculten"**. Esta solución tiene un inconveniente y es que la tabla tenía un borde gris y con esta propiedad también se oculta, pero alcanzamos a ver el fondo rojo de la misma, por lo que si quieres que se vean como los bordes, puede ser la forma.

La tabla **tipo 4** fue más que nada para que veas como se ven las celdas todas con borde redondeado, no se si esto también querias hacerlo, pero por si acaso también lo pongo.

Por último, la **tipo 5** la solución que planteas de que cada celda en cada esquina de la tabla, para que pueda verse el borde redondeado de la tabla. No es una solución muy practica, pero al menos de esta forma se puede solucionar el problema.

Creo que en tu caso, te sucede lo de la **tipo 2** y en  la 3 sería la solución con el `overflow: hidden`. Espero haberte aclarado tu dudas, comentame si aún no soluciona tu problema y en caso de que si, regalame un voto positivo. Éxitos.

Comment: Hola edgar te comento que le di color de fondo a toda la tabla y coloque la opcion overflow:hidden; y logre al fin la esquinas redondeadas en todos los navegadores... pero el problema que tengo ahora es que la tabla no muestra el color de borde de ninguna manera. Me pudiera ayudar con esto ?

Comment: Como te comente, ese es el pero del overflow. Cómo ves, el color que le puse de fondo a la tabla, es la que aparece ahora como borde rojo de la misma, por lo que te sugiero cambiar `border` por `background`. La otra opción es usar una sombra que simule un borde: `box-shadow: 0 0 0 1px black;`, de esa forma lograras lo mismo. Voy a editar mi respuesta para que lo veas.

Comment: Al final.. pudiste lograrlo?

Answer (score 0):

Si pones un color de fondo a las celdas que aplicas el `border-radius` te darás cuenta que sí se aplica, solo no se ve por el color.

```css
.tabla_recibido tr td:first-child {
  width: 150px;
  background: #511;
  padding-right: 30px;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

.tabla_recibido td:nth-child(2) {
  width: 130px;
  padding-right: 30px
}

.tabla_recibido tr:nth-child(2) {
  border-bottom: 0.5px solid
}

.tabla_recibido tr:nth-child(3) {
  border-bottom: 0.5px solid
}

.tabla_recibido tr:nth-child(4) {
  border-bottom: 0.5px solid
}

.tabla_recibido td:last-child {
  width: 250px;
  /*border-bottom-right-radius: 6px;
        border-left: 0.5px solid*/
}


/*.tabla_recibido tr:first-child td:first-child{border-top-left-radius: 20px}
    .tabla_recibido tr:first-child td:last-child{border-top-right-radius: 20px}
    .tabla_recibido tr:first-child td:only-child{border-top-right-radius: 20px; 
    border-top-left-radius: 20px}*/

.tabla_recibido h6 {
  font-size: 0.8em
}

.tabla_recibido td {
  padding: 2px;
  text-align: justify;
  /*border: 0.5px solid;*/
}

.tabla_recibido li {
  list-style: none;
}

.tabla_recibido {
  border: 1px solid;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
```

```html
<table class="tabla_recibido">
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="fila1">
    <td id="logo_recibido">
      <img src="../../../img/logo.png">
    </td>
    <td colspan="2">
      <h5><b>XXXXXXXX</b></h5>
      <h5>Nombre del trabajador</h5>
      <h5>Ruc: 17xxxxx</h5>
      <h5>Direccion: Avexxxxxxxxx</h5>
      <h5>Telefono: 097xxxxxxx</h5>
    </td>
    <td>
      <h3><b>Orden:</b></h3>
      <h1 id="orden"># 0000{!! $equipo->id !!}</h1>
      <ul>

        <li><b>Fecha de ingreso: </b>{!! date('d-m-Y',strtotime($equipo->created_at)) !!}</li>
        <li>Valor: $ ___________</li>
        <li>Abono: $ ___________</li>
        <li>Saldo: $ ___________</li>
      </ul>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="cuerpo_recibido">
    <td colspan="2">
      <h4>Datos del Cliente:</h4>
      <h5>Nombre: <small>{!! $equipo->cliente->nombres !!}</small></h5>
      <h5>Apellidos: <small>{!! $equipo->cliente->apellidos !!}</small></h5>
      <h5>Cédula: <small>{!! $equipo->cliente->cedula !!}</small></h5>
      <h5>Teléfono: <small>{!! $equipo->cliente->telefono !!}</small></h5>
      <h5>Dirección: <small>{!! $equipo->cliente->direccion !!}</small></h5>
    </td>
    <td colspan="2">
      <h4>Datos del Equipo:</h4>
      <h5>Identificador: <small>{!! $equipo->identificador !!}</small></h5>
      <h5>Marca: <small>{!! $equipo->marca->name !!}</small></h5>
      <h5>Modelo: <small>{!! $equipo->modelo !!}</small></h5>
      <h5>Color: <small>{!! $equipo->color !!}</small></h5>
      <h5>Daño: <small>{!! $equipo->descripcion !!}</small></h5>
      <h6>Los Equipos xxxxx abandonados por lo tanto <b><i>Ingxxx</i></b>, no se responsabiliza del la devolución del mismo.</h6>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2">
      <h6><b>NOTA:</b> El cliente declara ser el propietario legitimo del equipo, y que fue adquirido
        <b><i>Lítitamente</i></b>, por lo cual autoriza la reparacion en nuestro taller.</h6>
    </td>
    <td>
      <h4>Accesorios:</h4>
    </td>

    <td>


      <ul>
        <li>Chip_____</li>
        <li>Bateria_____</li>
        <li>Cargador_____</li>
      </ul>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2">
      <h5>Firma cliente</h5>
    </td>
    <td colspan="2">
      <h5>Firma conforme</h5>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Si aún así quieres agregarlo con compatibilidad para varios navegadores, puedes utilizar lo siguiente, pero solo aplica para navegadores viejos.

```
-webkit-border-radius: 10px;
-moz-border-radius: 10px;
border-radius: 10px;
```

**Actualización**

Si lo que deseas es poner las esquinas de la tabla redondeadas puedes hacerlo de la siguiente forma (ejemplo tomado de la siguiente [respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11273086/4987172)):

```css
table { 
    border: 2px solid #1FF;
    border-collapse: separate;
    border-left: 0;
    border-radius: 7px;
    border-spacing: 0px;
}
thead {
    display: table-header-group;
    vertical-align: middle;
    border-color: inherit;
    border-collapse: separate;
}
tr {
    display: table-row;
    vertical-align: inherit;
    border-color: inherit;
}
th, td {
    padding: 5px 4px 6px 4px; 
    text-align: left;
    vertical-align: top;
    border-left: 2px solid #F1F;    
}
td {
    border-top: 2px solid #4F1;
}
thead:first-child tr:first-child th:first-child, tbody:first-child tr:first-child td:first-child {
    border-radius: 7px 0 0 0;
}
thead:last-child tr:last-child th:first-child, tbody:last-child tr:last-child td:first-child {
    border-radius: 0 0 0 7px;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr><th>xxx</th><th>xxx</th><th>xxx</th></tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr><td>xxx</td><td>xxx</td><td>xxx</td></tr>
    <tr><td>xxx</td><td>xxx</td><td>xxx</td></tr>
    <tr><td>xxx</td><td>xxx</td><td>xxx</td></tr>
    <tr><td>xxx</td><td>xxx</td><td>xxx</td></tr>
    <tr><td>xxx</td><td>xxx</td><td>xxx</td></tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Correcto pero como puedo agregar los bordes redondeados a la tabla y que se note ??

Comment: cambiando el color como lo hice. No sé si esa es la respuesta o especifica más cuál es el objetivo

Comment: mi objetivo es que la tabla se vea redondeada en las 4 esquinas. Pero lo que no entiendo es porque si aplico la propiedad a la tabla en general no muestra el cambio. Por lo que me dices tengo que quitar el borde a la tabla y aplicar a cada celda que queda en las esquinas

Comment: Ahora le puse el color de borde al la celda y me doy cuenta que tampoco le aplica el radius. Solo el radius lo esta assumiendo el color-background

Comment: he editado mi respuesta con un ejemplo